# Is there a way with dune or opam to check that the installed ocaml compiler version is compliant with the specifications

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I have a dune-project file that specifies that my ocaml compiler should be at least 4.05.0

I created a configure file to check that all I need is properly installed (using a mix of `Unix.open_process_in "which <executabe>"` and `dune external-lib-deps --missing @@default`) but for OCaml version I had to write:

```ml
let e = Sys.ocaml_version in
match String.split_on_char '.' e with
| major :: minor :: patchlevel :: _
  when int_of_string major >= 4
       && int_of_string minor >= 5
       && int_of_string patchlevel >= 0 ->
    printf "%s@," e
| _ -> printf "version < 4.05.0"
```

But I don't like it that much because if I ever need to change the version requirement, it won't propagate to this check and I'll have to change it manually.

Is there a way to do it like I check that all the OCaml packages needed are installed with `dune external-lib-deps --missing @@default`? (And not necessarily only for the OCaml compiler but for each package that is bound to a version?)

Since the dependency specification is a logical expression I hoped that the solver behind opam could do it for me because I can't implement a SMT Solver in my configure file.